# Jasmine: unit test spying on call to nested function

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running unit test for angular app, I spy on a func1 if this called? But inside func1 I call func2, I want to spy if func2 is being called or not. How to structure my unit test?I am using jasmine.

Here is what I tried

**component.spec.ts**

```
let spyOnCreateEntitlement = spyOn(component,"func1").and.callThrough();
let spyOnSetRecord = spyOn(component,"func2").and.callThrough();
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(func1).toHaveBeenCalled();//passes
expect(func2).toHaveBeenCalled();//fails!!!!
```

**component.ts**

```
func1(){
 func2();
}

func2(){
 ...some logic...
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more code of `component.ts`? It may contain asynchronous stuff that needs some synchronization in your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to reproduce:
component.ts

```
    testFunction1() {
        this.testFunction2();
    }

    testFunction2() {
    }
```

spec.ts:

```
    it('should call functions', () => {
        let spyOnCreateEntitlement = spyOn(component, 'testFunction1').and.callThrough();
        let spyOnSetRecord = spyOn(component, 'testFunction2').and.callThrough();

        component.testFunction1();

        expect(spyOnCreateEntitlement).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(spyOnSetRecord).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

=> test passed. 
I guess the reason is that you have 'expect(func1).toHaveBeenCalled()', you should either have your spy name here OR component.func1

Comment: Hi  @Tatsiana, it didn't pass the   expect(spyOnSetRecord).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: In my example it passed, maybe you can provide more details on what kind of functions you have, do they have async code? How do you call the first function because in your test you don't execute it, just spy is creates